# Google Sheets - call query() for each item in a column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a table in Google Sheets with a "Ticker" column.

```
| Ticker |
| ------ |
| APPL   |
| AMZN   |
| GOOG   |
```

I'd like to use `GOOGLEFINANCE()` to return the ticker, date, and historical stock price for each ticker, like this:

```
| Ticker | Date     | Closing Price |
| ------ | ----     | ------------- |
| APPL   | 1/1/2019 | $100          |
| APPL   | 1/2/2019 | $101          |
| APPL   | 1/3/2019 | $102          |
| AMZN   | 1/1/2019 | $150          |
| AMZN   | 1/2/2019 | $151          |
| AMZN   | 1/3/2019 | $152          |
| GOOG   | 1/1/2019 | $200          |
| GOOG   | 1/2/2019 | $201          |
| GOOG   | 1/3/2019 | $202          |
```

When I run `=query(googlefinance(A2:A, "close", 1/1/2019, 1/3/2019, 1), "select '"&A2&"', Col1, Col2", 0)` I get the following:

```
| Ticker  | Date     | Closing Price |
| ------  | -------- | ------------- |
| "APPL()"|          |               |
| APPL    |          |               |
| APPL    | 1/1/2019 | $100          |
| APPL    | 1/2/2019 | $101          |
| APPL    | 1/3/2019 | $102          |
```

How do I iterate through the tickers and append the results into one table?

Answer (score 0):

[GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) already returns an array of values and will only return them for a single ticker input and therefore, you cannot set the ticker to be a range. Therefore, you will need to manually set your `GOOGLEFINANCE` functions one by one manually.

Alternatively, you can create an [Apps Script script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to make the [finace requests](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to a finance website and return their results. In that way you could programmatically iterate over you range of tickers and order the information as you please taking use of [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).